# How to store HEX in a uint8_t array?

Tags: c, mbed

I want to store the HEX value into a `uint8_t` array. Below is the code that I am trying to use and pass it to set the resource value:

```
const static uint8_t PSK_KEY[] = "31383031";
security->set_resource_value(M2MSecurity::Secretkey, PSK_KEY, sizeof(PSK_KEY) - 1);
```

Or do I need to set the `PSK_KEY` in ASCII?

Comment: What do you mean? Your code _is_ already using ASCII. `"31383031"`

Comment: Why do you subtract 1 from the key size, concerning to this example: https://docs.mbed.com/docs/mbed-client-guide/en/latest/Howto/ it's not done?

Comment: This is no valid C code. Please use correct language tags and don't spam with tags not related.

Comment: Please explain what exactly you are trying to achieve. `PSK_KEY` is the string `"31383031"`. Do you want to transform this into something like `uint8_t whatever[] = {0x31, 0x38, 0x30, 0x31};` ?

Comment: What is `unit8_t`? Do you mean `uint8_t`?

Comment: @Barmar yes he does. Can be deducted from the second line of his code. Just edited the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you mean.

"Store hex" (why do you write it in caps?) is a bit unclear.

If the value of the PSK is the four bytes 0x31, 0x38, 0x30, 0x31 then you need to write it differently to get the proper result:

```
static const uint8_t PSK_KEY[] = { 0x31, 0x38, 0x30, 0x31 };
```

of course those four are ASCII, so you can express the same data as text:

```
static const uint8_t PSK_KE[] = "1801";
```

Comment: @prem Sure, but that literal in C will not make the result be a 4-byte array holding the bytes whose values are those given (in hex). It will be a 9-byte string instead, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`PSK_KEY[]= { 0x31,0x38,0x30,0x31}`

OR

`PSK_KEY[]= { '1','8','0','1'}`